# Why would setting readPreference nearest generate not master errors?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are using a node stack to connect to a mongo replica set. Because our replicas are geographically distributed, we would like to use the readPreference option in the URI and set it to nearest. But when we do so, while performance is greatly improved, we start getting "not master" errors.

Am I misunderstanding the use of the flag?

We are using mongo 2.6.3 and we are using version 2.0.24 of the mongodb node library.

The URI for the connection is:

```
mongodb://mongo-1:27017,mongo-2:27017,mongo-3:27017,mongo-4:27017,mongo-5:27017/db?replicaSet=main&readPreference=nearest
```

Burc

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
You could append slaveOk to end of connection URI. readPreference tells mongodb that how you'd like to read data and slaveOk instructs that it's OK to read from secondaries (bit duplicate) but works.

e.g.

```
mongodb://mongo-1:27017,mongo-2:27017,mongo-3:27017,mongo-4:27017,mongo-5:27017/db?replicaSet=main&readPreference=nearest&slaveOk=true
```

please see `&slaveOk=true` and end of URI.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#read-preference

**Option 2:**
if above solution is not working, you'll need to modify code:

```
var client = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var uri= "mongodb://mongo-1:27017,mongo-2:27017,mongo-3:27017,mongo-4:27017,mongo-5:27017/db?replicaSet=main";
```

Please note that I have modified connection uri. Instead of setting readPrefference in Uri, I moved it to as db option in MongoClient.connect.

```
var options =  {db:{readPreference:"ReadPreference.NEAREST"}};
client.connect(uri, options, function(err, db){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
   db = db.collection('data');
   db.findOne({}, function(err, result){
       console.log(result); 
   }); 
});
```

I have tested in nodejs driver 2.2 and hopping it should work in 2.0 version too.

Comment: that's how i started and it didn't work. i believe slaveOk is obsolete now and readPreferences replaces it.

Comment: Thanks @machunter. I just updated my answer. can you try **Option 2** if possible. I'm not sure it will be viable and easy to achieve solution as you'll need to modify your code.

Comment: I haven't tried that since i was hoping that just modifying the URI would be enough... changing the code is not the most practical approach.

Comment: Agreed. that's why I said I'm not sure it it's viable or not.  MongoDB make it more explicit as reading from secondaries could be troublesome some time due to replication lag. Secondaries may not have up to date data. But... if you are really struggling with performance, it's good to invest some time and change your code in way that it reading from secondaries could be turned on and off with a simple configuration chnage.

Comment: I've tried your way, I don't think it's correct, I'm not seeing that the driver is trying to connect to the secondaries as it was doing when the I set it in the URI. And also if you read the link to the documentation you sent, you'll see that it says "readPreference=enum: The read preference for this connection. If set, it overrides any slaveOk value"

Comment: Yep. That's why I suggested you option 2 and version of driver I'm using which is 2.2+. It's fully tested solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was a bug in the driver which was fixed in 2.0.28, where findAndModify used the readPreference setting. Upgrading the driver to the latest release seemed to have fixed the problem.

[2.0.x drivers history](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/HISTORY.md)